# Installing cordova platform from local sources

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid

I would like to install android platform from local sources for my cordova project using local installed cordova tools, but i can't - it always ends with some errors.

More details:

**I used:**

nodejs v8.9.3
npm v5.6.0
cordova v8.0.0 (only local installation)
cordova-android v7.1.0

First i created pure empty project for testing it with few next commands:

```
npm i cordova@8
npx cordova create some-blank-app
cd some-blank-app
npm i cordova@8.0.0 cordova-android@7.1.0
npx cordova platform add ./node_modules/cordova-android
```

After that i always get same errors

```
(node:15714) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError
(node:15714) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So what am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: It looks like a bug.. - it works perfect with cordova@7.x

Comment: What's the problem with installing from the official Cordova servers?